# How do I pipe HEREDOC to head?

Tags: python, bash, zsh

I have this command which executes python and limits it to a half a second of execution time.

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | gtimeout 0.5 python
print "Hi"
print "hello"
PYSTUFF
```

This works great. However if someone were to write something like this:

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | gtimeout 0.5 python
while(True): print("hi")
PYSTUFF
```

It will kill the execution and I'll be left with about 12.5 mb of `"hi"`. I want to pipe the output of this command to `head` so that I can limit the output to maybe the first 500k lines or so. I just can't figure out where to put this:

```
| head -n 500000
```

I tried putting it at the end of the HEREDOC and that is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place it after the gtimeout call.

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | gtimeout 0.5 python | head -n 500000
while(True): print("hi")
PYSTUFF
```